# Meat Thermometer

Tags: equipment, meat

Bought a new Food Network meat thermometer.  Temperature never changes. Always stays at 160 even before use.  What is wrong?  How do I correct?

Comment: peel the transparent label that reads 160 off the face of the LCD screen.

Comment: @CosCallis Please make that an answer, so that Ruthie can approve it and it stays here for others to see.

Answer (score 1):

Peel the transparent label that reads 160 off the face of the LCD screen.